# what means these examples about session fixation?

Tags: php, session-fixation

the first example

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['count'])) $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
else ++$_SESSION['count'];

echo $_SESSION['count'] . "<br />";
?>
```

the second example

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['initiated']))
{
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['initiated'] = 1;
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['count'])) $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
else ++$_SESSION['count'];

echo $_SESSION['count'] . "<br />";
```

I can find the only different is if I use two different URLs(eg: http//localhost/test?PHPSESSID=123; http//localhost/test?PHPSESSID=456) the first script will count up again from zero, but the second will continue count

so what do two examples mean? and what does it want to tell me?

Comment: The only difference between these scripts is the `session_regenerate_id()` chunk. Are you asking why that changes the behavior of the script?

Comment: yes, I don't understand these scripts' results, when I added the session_regenerate_id(), the $_SESSION['count'] was still counting

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my first answer was too hasty. Check [This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) out. PHP.net says:

"session_regenerate_id() will replace the current session id with a new one, and keep the current session information."

Comment: The session_regenerate_id() just renames the session id and keeps all session variables intact.

Comment: If the $_SESSION['count'] variable is reset when the script execute session_regenerate_id(), why the $_SESSION['count'] does not count up again form zero?

Answer (score 0):

session_regenerate_id() if it can, will submit a cookie to keep the session details.
Think of it as a extended session for the user. So that if the user closes their browser, the user session can be recalled.